# Android layout inflater out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, layout-inflater

I'm getting this error only sometimes and only in one device:

```
  04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java

:746)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at com.app.appgym.ActorRutina.onCreateView(ActorRutina.java:36)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    ... 22 more
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3392)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:460)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:180)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
04-09 16:05:22.016: E/AndroidRuntime(31843):    ... 25 more
```

The device im using is xperia s, but in another smartphone I also use, zte v967s, this error never happens. 
How could I avoid this memory problem?

Comment: Can you share your layout file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use android:largeHeap="true" under the application tag of your manifest file, might solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the best sollution in all cases... look at android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

This device might just have smaller amount of memory. Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html - you should keep your hierarchy as flat as possible.

Also, you can track down what allocates the biggest chunk of memory using any of these techniques: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html